# Cannot read property 'open' of undefined - menu in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, contextmenu

I have issue with action in my menu.
I using material menu and icons for this project.
The wain menu code looks like this:

```
<mat-menu #rootMenu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
  <ng-template matMenuContent let-element="element">
    <div *ngFor='let item of contextMenu' (click)="item.action(element)">
      <button *ngIf='!item.seperator' mat-menu-item [disabled]="item.disabled">
        <mat-icon>
          {{item.icon}}
        </mat-icon>
        <span>
          {{item.name}}
        </span>
      </button>
      <mat-divider *ngIf='item.seperator'></mat-divider>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</mat-menu>
```

Now i show you my menu element model:

```
export class MenuElement {
  id?: string
  name?: string
  tooltip?: string
  icon?: string
  action: (element : any) => void
  disabled?: boolean = true
  seperator?: boolean = false
}
```

And at the end, part of menu in component ts:

```
 constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {      //#1
 ...
 this.contextMenu = 
 ...
 {
        name: 'Rename',
        icon: 'edit',
        action: this.openRenameDialog,
        disabled: true
 },
 ...
```

And openRenameDialog function:

```
  openRenameDialog(element: FileElement) {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(RenameDialogComponent);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(res => {
      if (res) {
        element.name = res;
        this.elementRenamed.emit(element);
      }
    });
  }
```

And at the end, this is my error:

> core.js:5828 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
>       at Object.openRenameDialog [as action] (lib-common.js:4857)
>       at FileExplorerComponent_ng_template_8_div_0_Template_div_click_0_listener
>   (lib-common.js:4550)
>       at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:21593)
>       at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:21635)
>       at HTMLDivElement. (platform-browser.js:934)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:400)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:40744)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
>       at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
>       at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:481)

Any ideas what i need to do?

## Edit 1

Dialog was injected, look #1

Comment: Did you inject Dialog to component constructor ?

Comment: you probably need to inject the dialog in the constructor ```constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}```

Comment: Dialog was injected, i update it. Reason is somewhere else

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you create a minimal Stackblitz example?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the syntax of the "openRenameDialog" method to

```
openRenameDialog = (element: FileElement) => {
    // etc 
}
```

This is probably happening because when you assign `action: this.openRenameDialog`, the binding to `this` is targeting the context of the method instead of the context of the class (which is where dialog is actually defined).

In older versions of JS you would need to use `bind` to reference the correct context. However, with the inclusion of "fat arrows" in ES6, this binding is automatically being done for you.